# Как отключить сглаживание в Android, при выведении bitmap?

Tags: android, android-canvas

Нужно вывести картинку (pixel art) на канвас, без сглаживания. Я отключил его в paint, но при растяжении картинки она всё равно сглаживается. В чём может быть проблема?

Самое странное, что на некоторых устройствах всё работает отлично, ничего не сглаживается.

```
public class DrawThread extends Thread {

private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

private volatile boolean running = true;
private Paint backgroundPaint = new Paint();

private Bitmap bitmap;
private Matrix matrix;



{
    backgroundPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    backgroundPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    backgroundPaint.setFilterBitmap(false);
    backgroundPaint.setAntiAlias(false);
    backgroundPaint.setDither(false);
}

public DrawThread(Context context, SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {

    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.wall);
    matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(10,10);

    this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
}

public void requestStop() {
    running = false;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (running) {
        Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
        if (canvas != null) {
            try {
                canvas.drawRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), backgroundPaint);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,matrix,backgroundPaint);

            } finally {
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

[image: сглаженная картинка]

Comment: Попробуйте поместить ваши drawable-ресурсы, которые блурятся, в папку drawable-hdpi, иначе Adnroid будет блуррить несмотря на ваш Paint объект.

Comment: Мне кажется вы желаете странного. Как же это так матрица масштабирования не будет "размывать" пиксели при масштабе не кратном степени двойки? Это же самое что ни на есть by design. Ну напишите свой транслятор битмапа например с порогом установки цвета пикселя. Или антиблюр-фильтр для обработки результата матричного преобразования.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4822358/9765252 пробывали?